# Block scoping of self and dot accessors inside animateWithDuration block method of UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, core-animation

Is it safe to access self and self's properties via dot accessors inside of an animateWithDuration block?

I'm having some animation glitches related to expanding self frame especially when I call self.frame, as in below:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval animations:^{
    self.citiesTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 120);
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220);
} completion:^(BOOL completed){
    if (completed) {
        self.citiesTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 120);
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220);
        [self.citiesTableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the block isn't retained by the view, it is safe to capture `self` strongly inside the block. Problems arise, when blocks capture `self` strongly (intentionally or by mistake, by accessing instance variables) and are retained by the view, like for instance, when using a block as the response of a bar button item. Here, the block is executed and discarded.